# Trailing spaces during integer to string conversion in power shell script

Tags: powershell

I am converting an integer to string . The string is appended with spaces at the end . I used Trim() function but still its giving trailing spaces towards the end. What is the funny thing happening here?. I use PS version 5.

Code:

```
$OutputFileDtls = $OutputFileDtls + "/" + $Global:FilenmPathCur + ":" + $CurRecCnt.ToString().Trim() + ";"  
        Add-Content -Value "$TimeinSec Log: Details of the output files found for current job: $jobname in the $mastTableNm table are Count: $OutputFileRecCnt Details: $OutputFileDtls " -Path $logfile
```

output:

```
2020-02-19 14:21:38 Log: Details of the output files found for current job: BD_PR_AMS_FNTR_DATAVALIDATION_BLOCK1 in the [dbo].[DSTalendJobs] table are Count: 0 Details: /Dataproviders/Temp/Validated/GCW/FinalTier/AMS/gcw_finaltier_ams_565_20191124_03_58_37_data_validation.valid:0;/Dataproviders/Temp/Rejected/GCW/FinalTier/AMS/gcw_finaltier_ams_565_20191124_03_58_37_data_validation.reject:0;/Dataproviders/Temp/Blocked/GCW/FinalTier/AMS/gcw_finaltier_ams_565_20191124_03_58_37_cutoffdate.block                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       :0
```

Here you can see a zero at the end after trailing spaces which shouldn't come in the first place

Comment: So far I fail to see "a zero at the end after trailing spaces". Can you please provide a more minimal example, that allows people to quickly reproduce the problem that you are experiencing?

Comment: is the trailing space showing in `$OutputFileDtls` itself OR is it only showing in the `Add-Content` target file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also trim FilenmPathCur:
`$Global:FilenmPathCur.Trim()`

You also have a trailing space in the `Add-Content` value.